# Why do we stop at double cosets and do not consider triple, ... n-ple cosets?

Tags: group-theory

The obvious answer seems to be that a group has only two sides, and once you're done taking quotients on the left and on the right, you can't quotient by another subgroup from another side.

But if $G$ is a group with subgroups $H$ and $K$, why can we not consider a quotient like $G/H/\bar K$, where $\bar K$ is the image of $K$ in $G/H$ and the whole should be understood as the set of cosets $xHK$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you cannot build an equivalence relation on a double quotient on one side. Note that you can't get transitivity:

$$\begin{aligned} &a = xhk \\ &b = xh'k' \\ &b = yh''k'' \\ &c = y'''k'''\end{aligned}$$ so that $a \sim b$ and $b \sim c$, but a bit of manipulation will show that you can get $a\sim c$ when you have at most one coset on each side.

Comment: You ask, you answer...weird.

Comment: Honestly...  trying to profit off of asking a question and answering lol

Comment: I thought answering one's own question was OK!  Am I missing.something?

Comment: When you give it a shot after you *honestly* don't know the answer, @RobertLewis. For example, after being given some explanations, some hints, etc. In this case the OP asked something and right away posted an answer, so what's the point?

Comment: @DonAntonio when you write a question there is a button right the end which says "answer your own question to share your knowledge Q&A style". What happened to me was that I realized the answer to my question as I finished writing it, so instead of throwing everything out, I decided to also answer it. This way I could also help other people, and possibly receive comments on my answer being complete or not. Maybe there are even other far-fetched, yet interesting reasons that I did not see.

Comment: Since you *did answer* your question immediately after being posted and did *not* add the answer as self work on your own question it looked funny, @Rodrigo. I really don't care.

Comment: Alternative answer: because double cosets already give me a headache!

Comment: @Rodrigo Thanks for answering and not deleting. Helped me out.